# Show/Hide LineGraph/BarGraph on checkbox listener, BarGraph not working. MPAndroidChart Android

Tags: android, checkbox, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am using MPANDROIDCHART library to show a chart,
in combine chart, I am showing Line chart and Bar Chart. My requirement is when  Line checkbox true it should show line and when Bar checkbox is true it should show barchart.
When I uncheck line checkbox Line chart should hide.
and when uncheck bar checkbox bar chart should hide.

My code is working in case of Line but in case of Bar chart, it is not working I am getting the Nullpointer exception.

Below is my code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.swytch.chartdemo.MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chechbToken"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="line" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chechbEnergy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bar" />

</LinearLayout>



  <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
      android:id="@+id/chart1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ScatterData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ScatterDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CombinedChart mChart;
    private final int itemcount = 12;
    private CheckBox chechmnb,chechabc;

    protected String[] mMonths = new String[] {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"
};

    private XAxis xAxis;

    private BarData barData;
    private LineData lineData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        checkBoxInitialiozation();
        chartInitialization();
        setChartDataBasic();
     }


     private void checkBoxInitialiozation() {

         chechabc = findViewById(R.id.chechbEnergy);
         chechmnb = findViewById(R.id.chechbToken);

         chechabc.setChecked(true);
         chechmnb.setChecked(true);

         chechabc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                 if (!b) {
                    if (!chechmnb.isChecked()) {
                        chechabc.setChecked(true);

                    } else {
                         chechabc.setChecked(false);
                      }

                 }
                 setChartData();

             }
           });
           chechmnb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, 
 boolean b) {
                 if (!b) {
                     if (!chechabc.isChecked()) {
                       chechmnb.setChecked(true);
                   } else {
                        chechmnb.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
                setChartData();
            }
        });
    }
     protected float getRandom(float range, float startsfrom) {
         return (float) (Math.random() * range) + startsfrom;
     }

     private void chartInitialization() {

         mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
         mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
         mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
         mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
         mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);

         // draw bars behind lines
         mChart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{
                 CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR,CombinedChart.DrawOrder.LINE
         });

         Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
         l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
         l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
         l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
         l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
         l.setDrawInside(false);

         YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
         rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
         rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
         rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

         YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
         leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
         leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

         xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
         xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
         xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
         xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

     }

     private LineData generateLineData(ArrayList<Entry> entries) {

         LineData d = new LineData();
         LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Token");

         set.setLineWidth(2.5f);

         set.setCircleRadius(3f);
         set.setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
         set.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
         set.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
       set.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        set.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
         //to draw value in side graph
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        d.addDataSet(set);

       return d;
    }

   private BarData generateBarData(ArrayList<BarEntry> entries) {

        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(entries, "Energy");
        set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    set1.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    //to draw value inside graph
    set1.setDrawValues(false);

    float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset

    BarData d = new BarData(set1);
    d.setBarWidth(barWidth);

    return d;
   }
   private void setChartDataBasic() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entriesBarEntry = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> entriesLineEntry = new ArrayList<Entry>();


        entriesBarEntry.clear();
        entriesLineEntry.clear();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
            entriesLineEntry.add(new Entry(index + 0.5f, getRandom(15, 5)));

         entriesBarEntry = getBarEnteries(entriesBarEntry);

         try {
             if (mMonths.length > 0) {
               xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
                   @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                    return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
                }
            });

            barData = generateBarData(entriesBarEntry);
            lineData = generateLineData(entriesLineEntry);
            setChartData();
        } else {

            mChart.setData(null);
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "setChartData: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


  public void setChartData() {

    CombinedData chartData = new CombinedData();
    if (chechabc.isChecked())
        chartData.setData(barData);
    if (chechmnb.isChecked())
        chartData.setData(lineData);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(chartData.getXMax() + 0.25f);
    mChart.setData(chartData);
    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.invalidate();

  }


   private ArrayList<BarEntry> getBarEnteries(ArrayList<BarEntry> entries) {
    entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 20));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 10));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 80));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 40));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 20));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6, 60));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(7, 22));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8, 15));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9, 45));
    return entries;
  }
 }
```

**Facing Exception**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: 
com.swytch.chartdemo, PID: 10510

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData.getDataSetCount()' on a null 
object reference
                                                                      at 
 com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer
 .initBuffers(BarChartRenderer.java:61)
                                                                      at 
 com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.CombinedChartRenderer
.initBuffers(CombinedChartRenderer.java:82)
                                                                      at 
 com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase
 .notifyDataSetChanged(BarLineChartBase.java:326)
                                                                      at 
  com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.setData(Chart.java:304)
                                                                      at 
  com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
 .setData(CombinedChart.java:94)
                                                                      at 
   com.swytch.chartdemo.MainActivity
  .setChartData(MainActivity.java:240)
                                                                      at 
  com.swytch.chartdemo.MainActivity$1
  .onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:93)
                                                                      at 
  android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:154)
                                                                      at 
  android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:113)
                                                                      at 
  android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:118)
                                                                      at 
  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                                                                      at 
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at 
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                      at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at 

  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
  .run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                      at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

OutputImage :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: here is the issue,
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData.getDataSetCount()' on a null 
object reference
                                                                      at 
 com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer
 .initBuffers(BarChartRenderer.java:61)

on line 61 the BarData is null

Comment: BarChartRenderer, CombinedChartRenderer that classes are not mine.
It's library class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your setChartData method with:

```
public void setChartData()
{
    CombinedData chartData = new CombinedData();
    if(chechabc.isChecked() && chechmnb.isChecked())
    {
        chartData.setData(barData);
        chartData.setData(lineData);
    }
    else if (chechabc.isChecked())
    {
        LineData ld = new LineData();
        ld.clearValues();
        chartData.setData(ld);
        chartData.setData(barData);
    }

    else if (chechmnb.isChecked())
    {
        BarData bd = new BarData();
        bd.clearValues();
        chartData.setData(bd);
        chartData.setData(lineData);
    }

    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(chartData.getXMax() + 0.25f);
    mChart.setData(chartData);

    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

[image: With both datasets]

[image: Bar Data Only]

[image: Line Data Only]

Comment: This will work bro I tested it. Do contact me if you need further assistance.Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as follows.

```
public void setChartData() {

    CombinedData chartData = new CombinedData();
    boolean dataAvailable = false;
    if (chechabc.isChecked()) {
        chartData.setData(barData);
        dataAvailable = true;
    }
    if (chechmnb.isChecked()) {
        chartData.setData(lineData);
        dataAvailable = true;
    }
    if (dataAvailable) {
        mChart.setData(chartData);
    } else {
        mChart.setData(null);
    }
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(chartData.getXMax() + 0.25f);
    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```